# Dúvida de Table com colspan do HTML5

Tags: html5

Estou tentando, aplicar os titulos Fat. Credito para as colunas Data de Canc. de PV, Canal Contratação Cred. e Bandeira e Fat. Flex para Agência/Conta Dom. Ant., Agência/Conta Dom. Atual, Data início de Dom. e Canal Contratação Alt. Dom. e deixar as 3 primeiras sem nada, mas não estou conseguindo direito. Segue abaixo o código HTML:

```html
<table style='width:80%'>
                  <tr><td><b> 2) Credenciamento e Domicílio</b></td></tr>
                  </table>
                  </center>

                  <table class='table-custom table table-striped table-hover table-vcenter' style='width:100%'>
                      <thead>
      <tr>
         <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="3">Fat. Credito </th>
         <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="3">Fat. Flex </th>
      </tr>
                          <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>CNPJ14</th>
                          <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>PV</th>
                          <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 11.00%'>Data de Creden.</th>
                          <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 11.00%'>Data de Canc. de PV</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 5.00%'>Canal Contratação Cred.</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>Bandeira</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>Agência/Conta Dom. Ant.</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>Agência/Conta Dom. Atual</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 11.00%'>Data início de Dom.</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 5.00%'>Canal Contratação Alt. Dom.</th>
                      </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <td align='center' valign='middle' style='border-top: 1px solid #000; line-height: 0.1em; margin: 0px 0 5px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;'>
                       <p>Teste</p>
                       </td>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Estou tentando acertar os tr's com o colspan, mas nada, alguém já fez algo do tipo que possam me dar uma dica?

Abraços comunidade!

Comment: Tente alterar os <th> onde estão os colspan para <td>.

Comment: Olá Sumback, obrigado pela ajuda, ainda não deu certo, alterei os ths do colspan para td e continua igual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara é só deixar um `TH` vazia com `colspan="3"` isso vai "empurrar" as outra para traz

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<table style='width:80%'>
    <tr>
        <td><b> 2) Credenciamento e Domicílio</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class='table-custom table table-striped table-hover table-vcenter' style='width:100%'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="" colspan="3"></th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="3">Fat. Credito </th>
            <th style="border: 1px solid black;" colspan="3">Fat. Flex </th>
        </tr>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>CNPJ14</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>PV</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 11.00%'>Data de Creden.</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 11.00%'>Data de Canc. de PV</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 5.00%'>Canal Contratação Cred.</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>Bandeira</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>Agência/Conta Dom. Ant.</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 9.00%'>Agência/Conta Dom. Atual</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 11.00%'>Data início de Dom.</th>
        <th class='text-center' style='background-color: #ff7600; width: 5.00%'>Canal Contratação Alt. Dom.</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td align='center' valign='middle'
            style='border-top: 1px solid #000; line-height: 0.1em; margin: 0px 0 5px; padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;'>
            <p>Teste</p>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado hugocsl era bem simples, obrigado pela ajuda e de todos que colaboraram

Comment: @LeandroAzevedo as vezes a ente demora para entender como a tablea funciona rss. Legal que resolveu, depois se vc achar que a resposta é essa mesmo e não aparecer nada que vc ache mais adequado lembre-se de marcar o `✔` beleza :)

Comment: Sim, trabalho a um bom tempo com HTML, as dúvidas vem mais nas Tables mesmo, obrigado.